# limit checked checkboxes jquery ui easely

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Just simply want to limit the number of checkboxes, but actualy my code  desallow all checkbox when lengh > 3 , whats wrong..

http://jsfiddle.net/mbAwC/11/

```
$('.limit :checkbox').change(function () {
    var $cs=$(this).closest('.limit').find(':checkbox:checked');
    if ($cs.length > 3) {
        this.checked=false;$('.limit :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').button( "refresh" );
    }
});
```

regards 
Jess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `removeAttr('checked')`

```
$(function() {
    $(".limit").buttonset();
    $('.limit :checkbox').change(function () {
        var $cs=$(this).closest('.limit').find(':checkbox:checked');
        if ($cs.length > 3) {
            this.checked=false;
            $('.limit :checkbox').button( "refresh" );
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mE4vc/)

Comment: no i tryed but for somme unknow reasons, you'll not able to uncheck all checkboxes with this method, try it..

Comment: no its ok, pb was some clik seems difficult with thoses buttons.. don't know why, i thought thats the last button can't be unckeck but it can, with difficults click..do you know why ?!

Answer (score 0):

`$('.limit :checkbox').removeAttr('checked')` is wrong. It will uncheck all your checkboxes.

Perhaps you meant `$(this).removeAttr('checked')` (but you already have `this.checked=false`)?

Answer (score 0):

Set checked to `false`, then call `button('refresh')`:

```
$(this).prop('checked', false).button('refresh');
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbAwC/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".limit").buttonset();

    var max = 3;
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]', '.limit');

    checkboxes.change(function () {
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max).button('refresh');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mbAwC/21/